# objects.update_or_create() creates a new record in database rathe than update exisiting record

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have created a model in Django and for which I get the data from an API. I am trying to use the `update_or_create` method for getting the data from the API and into my database. However, I may be confused on how it works.

When I run it for the first time it adds the data into the database as expected, however if I were to update one of the fields for a record - the data from the API has changed for the respective record - and then run it again, it is creating a new record rather than updating the existing record.

So in the scenario below, I run it and the count for record `Commander Legends` is `718`, which I then update manually in the database to be `100`. When I run it again, it creates a new record with count of `718`

With my understanding of it, it should of updated the record rather than create a new record.

**views.py**

```py
def set_update(request):
    try:
        discover_api = requests.get('https://api.scryfall.com/sets').json()
        set_data = discover_api['data']
        while discover_api['has_more']:
            discover_api = requests.get(discover_api['next_page']).json()
            set_data.extend(discover_api['data'])
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')

    sorted_data = sorted(set_data, key=lambda k: k['releaseDate'], reverse=False)

    for i in sorted_data:
        Set.objects.update_or_create(
            scry_id=i.get('id'),
            code=i.get('code'),
            name=i.get('name'),
            type=i.get('set_type').replace("_", " ").title(),
            release_date=i.get('released_at'),
            card_count=i.get('card_count'),
            is_digital_only=i.get('digital', False),
            is_non_foil_only=i.get('nonfoil_only', False),
            is_foil_only=i.get('foil_only', False),
            block_name=i.get('block'),
            block_code=i.get('block_code'),
            parent_set_code=i.get('parent_set_code'),
            tcgplayer_id=i.get('tcgplayer_id'),
            last_modified=date.today(),

            defaults={
                'scry_id': i.get('id'),
                'code': i.get('code'),
                'name': i.get('name'),
                'type': i.get('set_type').replace("_", " ").title(),
                'release_date': i.get('released_at'),
                'card_count': i.get('card_count'),
                'is_digital_only': i.get('digital', False),
                'is_non_foil_only': i.get('nonfoil_only', False),
                'is_foil_only': i.get('foil_only', False),
                'block_name': i.get('block'),
                'block_code': i.get('block_code'),
                'parent_set_code': i.get('parent_set_code'),
                'tcgplayer_id': i.get('tcgplayer_id'),
                'last_modified': date.today(),
            }
        )
    return redirect('dashboard:sets')
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: It will only update if the `scry_id=i.get('id')`, `code=i.get('code')`, etc. so if all filters are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [**`update_or_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create), you have basically two parts:

1. the named parameters which do the *filtering*, only if they can find a record that matches all the filters, it will update that record; and
2. the `defaults=…` parameter, which is a dictionary of values that will be used to *update* or *create* that record.

If you thus want to update only the `card_count` and `last_modified`, it looks like:

```
Set.objects.update_or_create(
    scry_id=i.get('id'),
    code=i.get('code'),
    name=i.get('name'),
    type=i.get('set_type').replace('_', ' ').title(),
    release_date=i.get('released_at'),
    is_digital_only=i.get('digital', False),
    is_non_foil_only=i.get('nonfoil_only', False),
    is_foil_only=i.get('foil_only', False),
    block_name=i.get('block'),
    block_code=i.get('block_code'),
    parent_set_code=i.get('parent_set_code'),
    tcgplayer_id=i.get('tcgplayer_id'),
    defaults={
        'card_count': i.get('card_count'),
        'last_modified': date.today()
    }
)
```

If you thus add `card_count` at the `kwargs`, it will *only* update the record if the `card_count` matches completely, so if both `defaults` and the `kwargs` contain the same values, you basically will either do nothing in case a record exists with all the values in place, or create a new one if no such record is present.